# I want to broadcast an pytorcc tensor of dimension (a,b,c) onto an array of dimension (b,c) to get an output of dimension (a,c) how do I do this?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch, array-broadcasting

I have two pytorch tensors,

```
A.shape = [416, 20, 3]
B.shape = [416,20]
```

I want to produce

```
C = matmul(A,B)
C.shape = [416,3]
```

Ie for each of the 416 20x3 arrays in A, find the corresponding 20X1 array in B and   compute `torch.matmul(A_i,B)`. Set that 3x1 array the i index of the output index. How do I make the broadcasting work out like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, use torch.einsum

```
# generate two random tensors for illustration purpose
A = torch.normal(mean=0.0, std=1.0, size=(416,20,3))
B = torch.normal(mean=0.0, std=1.0, size=(416,20))

C = torch.einsum('ijk,ij->ik', A, B)
print(C.shape) # will output (416,3)
```

Comment: That worked! Now I'm just getting CUDA runtime errors because whatever I'm doing is creating a really messed up compute graph. Thanks for helping me get to next error!

Comment: Since my answer solved your problem, would appreciate if you could accept this as the answer!